# Why are some cells not formatting correctly?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet, I apply conditional formatting rules to each row, and the first column appears to be formatting correctly, but the rest of the columns seem to not be. [image]

Look at I6 for example, it should be green because it's less than B6, but it's red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "custom formula" and use:

```
=D6=$B6
```

on range `D6:O`

for red use:

```
=D6<>$B6
```

Comment: I had to do >= for green and < for red, but yeah, that worked!